# wp_nav_menu add some element to container

Tags: menus, navigation

I've tried to hook `wp_nav_menu_args` to get an ID for the nav menu. I tried to add an element using javascript to container menu. But I never get the ID for the menu.

How can I add an element to a nav menu container from:

```
<nav id="my-menu"><ul><li>.....<li></ul></nav>
```

to:

```
<nav id="my-menu"><div class="additional"></div><ul><li>.....<li></ul></nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly straightforward, assuming you have access to the php files.

In the template that generates the menu, modify the [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) call to specify `container = FALSE`, and to provide the container and additional div manually in the surrounding HTML.

Without knowing your code in advance, one method would be to alter it as follows:

```
<nav id="my-menu"><div class="additional"></div>
    <?php 
        // Replicate the args from the original code for the most part
        $args = array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary', // Or whatever the original was
            'container'      => FALSE, // This tells it to not put a container around it
            'echo'           => TRUE, // again, whatever original was
            // .. any other args from original code ...
        );
        wp_nav_menu($args);
    ?>
</nav>
```

**EDIT:**
Knowing that the menu needs to be modified at generation, then the answer changes a bit:

You need to create a [custom menu walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)

Fundamentals below.  Modify based on your needs, reference the Walker article above:

```
class Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_el ( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 )     {
    // Copy all the start_el code from source, and modify
  }

  function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    // Copy all the end_el code from source, and modify
  }
}
```

Then, in your theme files, you can call wp_nav_menu like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
  'theme_location' => 'main',
  'container' => false,
  'menu_id' => 'nav',
  'depth' => 1,
  // This one is the important part:
  'walker' => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu
));
```

Comment: Hi @cale_b. Thanks for your response. Actually i need to modify nav menu when it generated because i have many menus. I have setting page at dashboard to determine which menu need to add  this div element. Can U give me another idea?